# Build opencv with opencv_contrib for iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I want to use xfeatures2d in opencv_contrib, However I can't build opencv2.framework with opencv_contrib for iOS.

I have tried build it with terminal by

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
```

It would give a `bash /module:Permission deny`.

Or if I try to build it with cmake-gui when I pressed config it said

```
Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid
```

Are there any solution for this?
Or are there better way for me to use xfeatures2d for iOS?